# Blurry text after scrolling in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

i've got an issue with text in IE, when the page loads the text looks neat and crisp, but when i double-click on some white space of the page the text looks like this:

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1249051422046133000.jpg](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1249051422046133000.jpg)

Is there a known solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You really need an IE support forum for this, it's not a programming related issue.

Comment: Fairly unhelpful comment there, Lazarus. This is as programming related as the other few hundred IE6 rendering-bug threads; very.

Comment: Agree with Oli there. Though I initially suggested trying it in other another version of IE, or Firefox. The problem could easily point to an issue with the CSS/HTML.

Comment: Could you post an HTML & CSS snippet that illustrates the issue?

Comment: If you dont have a minimum test case to show, could you post a link to a page with the problem?

Comment: Do you really have to provide good experience in IE6? Could you just ignore it and let it die? Leave this part unstyled to have it accessible.

Comment: Ok guys, found the issue, it was a jQuery effect that was firing on click on the document element and was "transitioning" the text to bold with an animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow this takes me back. Used to happen to me in some circumstances. If I remember correctly, all you need to do is add this to the first line of your CSS:

```
* { position: relative; }
```

Of course, that has ramifications of its own but just see if that works for you.

Edit, you can be more specific with your relative positioning (to fix it) [this evolt article](http://www.evolt.org/article/MSIE6_bug_with_floating_divs_and_spacers/17/23899/) goes some way to explain what is happening and what you need to do to fix it. It's along the same lines but you'll learn why IE6 is so rubbish at the same time =)

Comment: Well, it makes it disappear (as that div was positioned absolutely) which also makes no sense because the * selector is the looser against anything like an ID or a CLASS selector

Comment: Try setting `position:relative` on the text element (and adjusting for it, if that causes mischief)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/Step1.aspx) rendering issue - do you know if you have ClearType enabled or disabled in Windows?

Also, do you have any [opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) settings (`filter:alpha(opacity=x)`) in your CSS?

(IE6 applies ClearType rendering to text that has an opacity setting applied, whereas IE7, IE8 do not)

Comment: +1 I see this effect all the time in IE, and it's nearly always due to filter or other DX effects in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a background to the text element. This usually solves text rendering problems in IE6.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot, but are you using any IE specific [DirectX transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301995.aspx)? or, similarly,  if you don't have 100% control over the page, could something else like an ad be using one?

Comment: Happens on both of my monitors, haven't had a chance to test on any other machine ATM, good hint though

Answer (score 0):

This feels more like a driver or hardware related problem. Does this happen on IE6 on any machine? What if you reinstall your video drivers or tweak your display settings? What if you use a different video card?

Answer (score -4):

This has nothing to do with HTML/CSS code. Re-install your browser.